# If two kets are each orthogonal to a third ket, are they also orthogonal to each other?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space

Is there a proof for this either way?

For the normalized kets $\left|a \right\rangle, \left|b\right \rangle, \left|c\right \rangle $

If 
$$
\left\langle a\middle| b \right\rangle = 0 \quad\text{and}\quad \left\langle a \middle|c \right\rangle = 0,
$$
are $\left|b\right \rangle$ and $\left|c\right \rangle$ orthogonal to each other? That is, must $\left\langle b \middle|c\right \rangle = 0$?

Comment: No, e.g. $b=c$.

Comment: are a,b and c are supposed to be e.g. linearly independent?

Comment: @lemon That is an answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 12):

No. Just let $|b\rangle = |c \rangle$.

Answer (score 5):

In general no. If you think of $\left|a\right>$, $\left|b\right>$ and $\left|c\right>$ as vectors $\vec{a}$, $\vec{b}$ and $\vec{c}$, you can say that $\vec{a} = \vec{b} \times \vec{c}$, so that $\vec{a}$ is orthogonal to both $\vec{b}$ and $\vec{c}$, but this doesn't imply that $\vec{b} \cdot \vec{c} = 0$.

Answer (score -3):

(1) Answer is Yes in this example:

Consider complete set of orthonormal energy eigenfunctions of "particle in a box problem (infinite potential well)" in quantum mechanics.

Choose any 3 of them. If any one of these chosen 3 is orthogonal to remaining two, then these two are orthogonal to each other.

(2) Answer is No in the example of cross product of spatial vectors (as answered by MFH above).